# Ruby: How do you have optional first arguments? but default trailing arguments?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to have a method that is similar to this:

```
def method_with_optional(..., user = current_user, account = current_account)
...
```

because, I don't want to have to pass in current_user, and current_account every time.
but as long as a user object isn't passed, the user formal parameter shouldn't be over-ridden.

This way I could do the following

```
method_with_optional(params[:id])
```

or

```
 method_with_optional(params[:id], User.new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are named arguments, which is not supported in Ruby 1.8, but you may have some success with [arguments](https://github.com/rdp/arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, at the moment there is no built-in support for named parameters, you have to wait for Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to default arguments would be to assign the variable in the body of the method and to provide the User, Account arguments as a part of the params hash. You can check to see if the params contains a User and/or Account and then do the needful:

```
user = params[:user] || current_user
account = params[:account] || account
```

EDIT: If you cannot add things to the Params hash before invoking the method, then I don't know what you can do other than re-order the formal parameters in the method signature :)